# Exec in PHP doesn't work whereas the command works fine when run from the prompt

Tags: php, command-line, imagemagick, exec, tesseract

I am trying to perform an OCR using tesseract on a Windows based Apache server. It makes me mad. The following doesn't produce the expected  E:\zzz.txt file:

```
<?php

$command = "\"C:\\ocr\\tesseract.exe\" \"E:\\www\\test\\upload\\proofs\\src\\yehia.raef.jpg\" \"E:\\zzz\" 2>&1";

print $command;
exec("$command", $msg);
print_r($msg);

?>
```

When I run the program, here is what I get:

```
C:\Users\blob\Desktop>php ici.php
"C:\ocr\tesseract.exe" "E:\www\test\upload\proofs\src\yehia.raef.jpg" "E:\zzz" 2>&1

Array
(
    [0] => The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
)
```

But now if run the command directly from the prompt:

```
C:\Users\blob\Desktop>"C:\ocr\tesseract.exe" "E:\www\test\upload\proofs\src\yehia.raef.jpg" "E:\zzz" 2>&
Tesseract Open Source OCR Engine v3.02 with Leptonica
```

It works like a charm. Please note this kind of command perfectly works with other software such as ImageMagick...

Help!

Comment: What's your PHP version?

Comment: PHP 5.2.17 (cli) (built: Jan  6 2011 17:28:41)
Copyright (c) 1997-2010 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2010 Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.1.2, Copyright (c) 2002-2011, by Derick Rethans

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asuming that PHP has all the required permissions, in PHP versions earlier than PHP/5.3.0 running on Windows [you need to add an extra set of quotes](http://es2.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php#101579) around your full command:

```
<?php

$command = "\"C:\\ocr\\tesseract.exe\" \"E:\\www\\test\\upload\\proofs\\src\\yehia.raef.jpg\" \"E:\\zzz\" 2>&1";
if( PHP_OS=='WINNT' && version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.3.0', '<') ){
    $command = '"' . $command . '"';
}
print $command;
```

Comment: AMAZING! It works thanks to your support. I've been trying the fix that for days. I will consider upgrading my PHP version whenever possible and will keep your fix in the meantime. Thanks again.